# Can't authenticate properly with Chef API

Tags: scala, http, authentication, chef-infra, rsa

I have been attempting to put together a Scala library for making calls to Chef APIs but I keep getting this problem with authenticating the API calls.

I have triple checked and the private key is correct and all other headers. The code I am using is here:

https://github.com/LiamHaworth/shef/blob/master/src/main/scala/au/id/haworth/shef/ChefUtils.scala

and I am calling it like so

```
import au.id.haworth.shef.{RequestMethod, ChefUtils}
import au.id.haworth.shef.ChefServer

val key = io.Source.fromFile("user.pem").getLines.mkString("\n")

val chefServer = ChefServer("chef.example.com", 443, "https", "myorg", "myuser", key)

ChefUtils.sendRequestToServer(chefServer, RequestMethod.GET, "", "")
```

But I keep on getting this response from the server

`"{"error":["Invalid signature for user or client 'myuser'"]}"`

I am sure that the problem is simple and is staring me in the face but I can't see it so any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Worth [reading the doc](https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html) there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully got the API to authenticate. After using knife in debug mode to check what headers it was producing and adding a extra line into my mixlib to print the canonical headers I got it working.

With the canonical headers printed by mixlib I ran them through my signing code and found that I wasn't getting the same result with the signature so I dug a bit deeper to find I was signing my headers in the terribly wrong way.

I was digesting them not signing them! After swapping out `RSADigestSigner` for `Signature` in my code and changing the algorithm (`SHA1withRSA` to `RSA`) I finally got the headers to be signed the same as the mixlib ones!.

TL;DR I derped and used the wrong classes to do what I wanted to do. The changes I made can be seen in this commit:

https://github.com/LiamHaworth/shef/commit/2db2aa5b89cae272eecd0901be91533b61d2a6c3